# How to change only timezone without modifying the time in momentz

Tags: javascript, momentjs, datetime-format

I have date and time in 2016-06-21T10:00:00-07:00 format which represets 06/21/2016 5 PM in PST, I just want to change this to 06/21/2016 5 PM in EST and vice versa. How can I do it with momentz?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/FLhpq/5020/)

```
debugger;
var dateTime = moment('2016-06-21T10:00:00-07:00');
var newDateTime = dateTime.clone();
  newDateTime.tz('US/Eastern');
//dateTime = dateTime.utc();
    console.log(dateTime.utcOffset());

   console.log(newDateTime.utcOffset());
  console.log(newDateTime.utcOffset() - dateTime.utcOffset());
                //console.log(utc.format());
    dateTime =          dateTime.add(newDateTime.utcOffset(), 'minutes');
console.log(dateTime.format());
console.log(new Date(Date.parse(dateTime.format())).toJSON());
```

**EDIT:**

given input = 2016-06-21T08:00:00-07:00 (PST)

expected output = 2016-06-21T08:00:00-04:00 (EST)

So when I convert that to UTC then it should become

2016-06-22T15:00:00Z for PST
2016-06-22T12:00:00Z for EST

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are confused about how ISO8601 format works. This format always represents local time with a time zone offset. Thus `2016-06-21T10:00:00-07:00` represents June 21 2016 at 10 AM in a timezone that is currently UTC-7 (this could be US pacific, among many others).

It sounds like you want to take the local time, but put it in a new timezone. This opens up some interesting questions about why you are receiving the date in the format that you are. If the date is meant to be interpreted as an exact point on the global timeline, then the format you are receiving it in is good. If however, the date is meant to be interpreted as a local time (not relative to UTC), it might be worth considering the possibility that the format of the date needs to be changed at the source. For instance, if you are making an ajax request to an API, and it is returning a date in this format, but that date actually has no relationship to UTC, it would be good to try to change that API to only send the local time (without the offset). If you were able to do that, then the following code would work:

```
moment.tz('2016-06-21T10:00:00', 'America/New_York').format()
"2016-06-21T10:00:00-04:00"
```

If you are unable to do that, or if the date is meant to be interpreted as an exact point on the global timeline, but you wish to ignore that in your specific use case, that can be done. You will need to specify a parse format that ignores the timezone offset on your initial time stamp. The code would be as follows:

```
moment.tz('2016-06-21T10:00:00-07:00', 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss', 'America/New_York').format()
"2016-06-21T10:00:00-04:00"
```

You might benefit from the material in [this blog post](https://maggiepint.com/2016/05/14/moment-js-shows-the-wrong-date/), as it covers how ISO8601 format works, and how all of moment's constructor functions work.

Comment: I cannot remove the offset, but I have the same time in UTC format as well. So, I have total three inputs, one is dateTime with offset and dateTime in UTC and target timezone.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout `moment().utcOffset()` You can pass in the offset as parameter to this function and the date would use that locale.

Assuming you know beforehand the utcOffsets required which in your case are -420 and -240 or -300(EST with DayLightSaving). Below can be done

```
var dateTime = moment('2016-06-21T10:00:00-07:00');
dateTime.utcOffset(-420).format();
"2016-06-21T10:00:00-07:00"
dateTime.utcOffset(-240).format()
"2016-06-21T13:00:00-04:00"
```

NOTE: `With -04:00, it should 13:00:00 and not 07:00:00` - http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/est

EDIT: This answer was posted to the earlier version of question, where same time was needed in different timezones.  If it is incorrect, kindly please elaborate on how it is.
Thanks!

Comment: I edited my question with expected input and output.

Comment: Never special case time zone conversions. Because governments frequently change time zone rules, there are no guarantees that code that works today will work tomorrow. Use a time zone library that handles this for you. For more on the frequency of time zone changes: http://codeofmatt.com/2016/04/23/on-the-timing-of-time-zone-changes/

Comment: I am still getting the undesired result. @Maggie Pint, I am already using momentz fir this purpose.

Comment: I just changed my wrong representation of the dates in respective timezones. My original expectation was still the same. Anyway, I appreciate your effort to help me.